# Tangential and normal unit vectors from Radial and transverse unit vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises

If I'm given the velocity and the acceleration in terms of time in the form of polar coordinates (Radial and transverse unit vectors), then at any time t, am I able to get the acceleration and velocity vectors in the form of cartesian or tangential/normal coordinates?

I know that if I'm given the velocity and acceleration coordinates in the form of cartesian unit vectors I can get the radial and transverse / tangential and normal unit vectors and then reobtain these quantities any form but I can't figure out how to do it the way back.

-Note that acceleration isn't actually needed if velocity is given in terms of time.
-I am able to get the radius of curvature at that instant.

Comment: Does this help? [Converting polar velocity components to Cartesian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704371/convert-polar-velocity-components-to-cartesian)

Comment: Yes it does, thanks (the problem is solved now).